# Adding symbols to each element in a .csv file

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to add "<" and ">" to every element in my csv file. 
For example:

```
Data1,Data2,Data3
Number1,Number2,Number3
```

Converting to this:

```
<Data1>,<Data2>,<Data3>
<Number1>,<Number2>,<Number3>
```

My code:

```
with open(os.path.join(args["input"],file), 'r') as infile, open(os.path.join(args["output"], outfile), 'w') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t', quoting=*csv.ADD<>*) #Which quoting to use?
    writer.writerows(reader)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The [`quotechar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.quotechar) must be a single character, so what you're trying to do won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, parsing/writing a csv is so simple, it might not even be worth using the csv parser.

This code should work:

```py
with open(os.path.join(args["input"],file), 'r') as infile, open(os.path.join(args["output"], outfile), 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line:
            items = line.split(',')
            newitems = []
            for item in items:
                newitems.append('<{}>'.format(item))
            outfile.write('{}\n'.format(','.join(newitems)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Should work this way.

```
with open(os.path.join(args["input"], file), 'r') as infile,
    open(os.path.join(args["output"], outfile), 'w') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)

    for line in reader:
        writer.writerow(['<{}>'.format(f) for f in line])
```